# start video on div popup - load video on popup

Tags: jquery, video, html, popup, jwplayer

Okay not sure how this is even possible.

I have a series of jquery div popups, when each one appears i want them to start a video playing.

Which player should i use and how should i approach this, already have the divs but because they're set to display none, having the videos autoplay in JWplayer means they're playing before its poped up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div { position: absolute; width: 60px; height: 60px; float: left; display:none; }
.first { background-color: #3f3; left: 0;}
.second { background-color: #33f; left: 80px;}
.third { background-color: #3f3; left: 120px;}
.fourth { background-color: #33f; left: 300px;}
.fifth { background-color: #3f3; left: 400;}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/effects.slide.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><button>Run</button></p>
<div class="first">VIDEO 1 HERE</div>
<div class="second">VIDEO 2 HERE</div>
<div class="third">VIDEO 3 HERE</div>
<div class="fourth">VIDEO 4 HERE</div>
<div class="fifth">VIDEO 5 HERE</div>

<script>
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("div.first").delay(15060).show("puff", {}, 300).delay(116010).fadeOut(300);
      $("div.second").delay(40230).show("puff", {},300).delay(28990).fadeOut(300);
      $("div.third").delay(46180).show("puff", {},300).delay(27880).fadeOut(300);
      $("div.fourth").delay(71070).show("puff", {},300).delay(42050).fadeOut(300);
      $("div.fifth").delay(110080).show("puff", {},300).delay(17050).fadeOut(300);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

JWPlayer is a good player, but you should set autostart to false and use the JWPlayer Javascript API.

When the div pops up, use

```
[Your player name]().play()
```

To play the video. For example, your set up code begins with:

```
jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({...
...
```

Then you have to use

```
jwplayer().play()
```

.

Answer (score 1):

i'd recommend you tu use fancybox, is a nice 'lightbox' like library for jquery, its very simple and useful...

the link is: http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 1):

not to worry when we have some easy plugins, read the sores code carefully you can find your thing, here is some simple demo of load video on popup or some kind of light box. http://www.queness.com/post/1229/12-lightboxes-and-javascript-plugins-that-support-video-audio-flash-and-images or also this http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto.

Answer (score 0):

Use Shadowbox... its too good

This plugin supports most of the JavaScript Plugins like jQuery,Mootools,etc.

Link : http://www.shadowbox-js.com/support.html